# How to choose multiple rows every nth rows in R

Tags: r

I am currently working on a daily time series data which looks like this

| Date | streamflow |
| --- | --- |
| 1985-10-01 | 24 |
| 1985-10-02 | 6 |
| 1985-10-03 | 12 |
| 1985-10-04 | 14 |
| ... | ... |
| 2010-09-30 | 21 |

What I need to do is select the data from Oct 5 to Oct 24 from each year. I know use `slice()` and `seq()` can select a row every nth row, but I don't know how to have it work on selecting multiple rows. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the values in your "Date" column?  Are these `Date` objects?  Strings?

Comment: Yes, they are in Date objects. I looked at Gregor's answer, get it!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your `Date` column is a valid `Date` class, use `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

your_data %>%
  filter(
    month(Date) == 10 &
    day(Date) >= 5 &
    day(Date) <= 24
  )
```

If your data isn't `Date` class yet, throw in a `mutate(Date = ymd(Date))` before the `filter()` step.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works, totally forget the `Date` can be handled like that.